# React Js for complex ecommerce website development

Tags: reactjs, frameworks, e-commerce

We are thinking of remaking our more and more popular ecommerce website.

I am new to React, just went through some tutorials, read some articles on it. Learned about the use of React Native, React Render which wpuld probably be of use for eventual mobile apps and SEO improvements.

My question is if React is suited for such websites since it is mainly used to create SPAs. For ecommerce SEO is verry important, for obvious reasons, and React is not so good at this.

What would you suggest? Does anyone have experience with similar cases?

Please give us some advice on what we could use to make a complete and complex ecommerce website. What technologies/programming languages/framewors (even if other than React) should we use? Please suggest only modern technologies and libraries.

By the way, we are currently working with PHP and Yii framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General

At its base, React has nothing to do with SEO. It is just a way to build your web application through components (same as Vue or other frameworks).

Magento - a PHP shop system - is using React to render its frontend. You can find more on this special system in the [Magento Community](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/PWA-Studio-2-1-0-has-been-released/ba-p/127492). See also the Documentation for [Magento PWA](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/).

#### Experience

> What would you suggest? Does anyone have experience with similar cases?

PWA and storefronts with React/Vue/Angular are all very new. Everyone got the same problems. How to do SEO, synchronize data between storefront, APIs and the shop core system. Here's a list (to be continued).

- SEO: how to work with URLs, manual URL redirects for products/cms/categories/...
- SEO: Server side rendering is currently the best solution to handle googles crawler.
- How to sync products, other data and especially the cart while or after beeing offline.
- Extensions: How to integrate new or existing extensions which might already be installed in the conventional shop
- ...

Each community is trying to solve those issues. Every community learns from the other and if you choose a more or less active storefront, you should be good to go. But really keep in mind that (in my opinion) all of them are in alpha or beta state with a lot of changes you have to integrate into your own theme/extensions/etc.

#### Projects

Here are a few storefronts you can choose from. Most of them have an API you can adapt to support your own Shop system. I would go with a React storefront, because I found it the most readable solution and it has a huge community. But choose yourself.

- Magento PWA Studio (React)
- DEITY (React)
- Front-Commerce (React)
- Vue Storefront (Vue)
- ...

Comment: I did some further reading since. Yes PWA is a nice thing to have. And solutions for SEO are SSR (Server Side Rendering) or using a service like Prerender.io, plus some other tools like React Helmet and React Router (in case someone is working with ReactJS).